# Rotate rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

im trying to rotate the rows of a dataframe, where the firt rows is the last row, the second the first and so on

Original

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |

Result

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |

How i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.roll` from numpy:

```
import numpy as np

df['A'] = np.roll(df['A'], 1)
print(df)

# Output:
   A
0  6
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
```

Comment: I didn't know about roll, does it keep the same index? Extra +1 because of someone -1 everyone lol

Comment: @CeliusStingher. Numpy doesn't care about index so the values are correctly aligned into the column. Thanks for +1.

Comment: You are right, the issue I had in my answer which cause me to have to reset_index() was the `iloc[]`. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: np.roll looks best for such cases. TIL. +1 from me

Comment: Can it use with groupby of panda??

Comment: @AlexisOliveroAimaretti. Yes you can use it with `groupby` inside `apply(lambda x: np.roll(x, 1))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to use `np.arange()` with `iloc[]`. If you want the index to remain unaltered add `.reset_index()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df.iloc[np.arange(-1, len(df)-1)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Returns:

```
   A
0  6
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution with pandas only, this should do the job for you-

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[-1:], df.iloc[0:-1]])
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: I'm not the one who has downvoted, but your solution doesn't work. It gives different output than it's expected.

Comment: It worked fine for me. Can you please elaborate on what you wanted which didn't come this way? I've added the reset index line, maybe you wanted the indices to be reset. Does this work now?

Comment: Sure, I can. In your solution df.iloc[1:] gives us elements from 2 to 6 and df.iloc[0:1] gives 1. When you use pd.concat we get a series: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1. In the expected output we have: 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If you want to create it with your method you should do: pd.concat([df.iloc[-1:], df.iloc[:-1]]).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I misread the question. Thank you, I've corrected it. You got the idea of the approach and worked it yourself anyways :D